# How to create a manual sum up counter with record logs using Javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I need to create a manual input counter using app script editor.

I've already have my website design with a single input textbox, reset button and a disabled box.

What I want is when I input a number in the textbox and press 'Enter' it will be displayed in the disabled box.If I repeat the process the new number in the textbox will sum up to the value inside the disabled box.

I would also like to have a reset button for the disabled box.

Lastly, having a record log of values inside the disabled box.

I really need to finish this before this month ends.

Is this even possible to make by just using html, Javascript and app script?

Here's my code:

```
let box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
let box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
let historyContainer = document.getElementById("history");
let history = [];

//listen key enter press on the input
box1.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (e.key === "Enter" && e.target.value !== "") {
  box2.value = e.target.value;
  history.unshift(e.target.value);
  historyContainer.innerHTML += `<p>${e.target.value}</p>`;
  }
});
//reset the second box and
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  box2.value = "";
});
```

I've used this code and apparently when the disabled box has a value and I try to enter a new number inside the input box it just merged with the value inside the disabled box, the new value must sum up to the value inside the disabled box. Also, the history log record all values entered in the textbox and not the previous value in the disabled box.

How can I fix this?

Please someone help me

Comment: Provide us some code, so we can help you.

Comment: Please Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've already edit my post and paste the code. I hope someone can help me

Comment: Could you share the rest of your HTML, body included?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert datatype to number using parseFloat or number:

```
box2.value = Number(box2.value) + Number(e.target.value);
```

Live example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div>
  <p>
    <input id="box1" type="number" />
    <input id="box2" type="number" disabled />
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    <div id="history">History</div>
  </p>
</div>
<script charset="utf-8">
  let box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
  let box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
  let resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
  let historyContainer = document.getElementById('history');
  let history = [];

  //listen key enter press on the input
  box1.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.target.value !== '') {
      box2.value = Number(box2.value)+ Number(e.target.value);
      history.unshift(e.target.value);
      historyContainer.innerHTML += `<p>${e.target.value}</p>`;
    }
  });
  //reset the second box and
  resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    box2.value = '';
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```